# writing then reading entity does not fetch entity from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am having the following problem. I am now using the low-level
google datastore API rather than JDO, that way I should be in a
better position to see exactly what is happening in my code. I am
writing an entity to the datastore and shortly thereafter reading it
from the datastore using Jetty and eclipse. Sometimes the written
entity is not being read. This would be a real problem if it were to
happen in production code. I am using the 2.0 RC2 API.

I have tried this several times, sometimes the entity is retrieved
from the datastore and sometimes it is not. I am doing a simple
query on the datastore just after committing a write transaction.

(If I run the code through the debugger things run slow enough
that the entity has a chance of being read back on the second pass).

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated,

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The development server has the same consistency guarantees as the High Replication datastore on the live server.  A "global" query uses an index that is only guaranteed to be eventually consistent with writes.  To perform a query with strongly consistent guarantees, the query must be limited to an entity group, using an "ancestor" key.

A typical technique is to group data specific to a single user in a group, so the user can see changes to queries limited to the user's group with strong consistency guarantees.  Another technique is to use fancier client logic to update the client's local view as soon as the change is submitted, so the user sees the change in the UI immediately while the update to the global index is in progress.

See the docs on [queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html) and [transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html).

Comment: In my application I have a set of chat rooms. Each chat room is represented by a root-level ancestor entity and each user will be in only one chat room at a time. Hence all queries against any particular chat room should be strongly consistent. The problem arises when a user creates a chat room and then wants to retrieve a list of all available chatrooms. In this case the result set may be incomplete. I wonder about this eventual consistency. How long does "eventual" mean? I don't mind waiting as long as I can get consistent results. I cannot have a partial list or user can't select chatroom.

Comment: I have thought about making the change available in the UI immediately but I am always afraid of doing this because of possible synchronization issues besides making the code more complicated. Ideally I would like to get back all data from the server with whatever needed changes need to be present.

Comment: I guess since the query is only eventually consistent, I am going to have to give the user to enter the chat room name manually in case it is not present in the retrieved list?

Comment: If the UI shouldn't do anything else until the query is updated, it may be reasonable to poll.  For instance, the client can fire off the request that makes the change, then if that returns successfully it can issue another request that waits for the new thing to show up in the global query (sleep, query, sleep, query).  Be careful of cases where another request might delete the data you're waiting for.  While you can probably assume the query index is updated within seconds in the typical case, be sure to engineer for the atypical cases.

Comment: Note that while the query is eventually consistent, the availability of the entity by key is strongly consistent.  So the request that creates the entity can return the key to the UI, and it can use it with straight gets right away.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I can keep querying the server and sleeping until what I am waiting for shows up, but I am not sure I understand the part you mention where another request could delete the data. How could this happen? Interesting point about the key being available in a strongly consistent matter. However it seems to me that if I want to make sure I have a list of all available chat rooms it seems to me that at least in theory I cannot be guaranteed to have a complete list if I do a search which is not a search on just the keys.

Comment: But AFAIK keys look messy and I will not be able to present them to the user. The user needs to see the chat room names, and as far as I understand I cannot set the chat room name to be the key for the ChatRoom root entities.

Comment: If it's not possible in your app for another request to delete the data you're waiting for, then don't worry about it.  I'm just thinking about what could go wrong with trying to wait for the global index to update.  (And I can't think of another way to wait for the update than to perform a query that would use the global index.)  As for fetching by keys, I wasn't expecting you'd show the key to the user, just that the UI could use it to refer to the entity directly by key in a request parameter if it needed to.

Comment: Thank you Dan for your replies. I have one more question on this issue though. Suppose I issue a request that is eventually consistent such as creating a chat room entity, and that I poll the server until my chat room shows up. From that point onwards, can I be guaranteed that a request from another computer, perhaps one even more far away from the server, will also have the chat room show up when they issue a request to the server and get a response? That is, once the eventually consistent query becomes consistent in one location, is it guaranteed to become consistent everywhere at same time?

Comment: I ask because once I get my chat room object back I need to send a bunch of C2DM notifications over the cloud to all of the other computers/phones waiting for the chat room to show up and if the above does not hold then I will indeed have to send the key of the chat room entity created along with the C2DM message and I don't even know whether I can fit the key in the 1024 bytes or so allowed by C2DM. Plus, all the other phones would have to poll the server at that point if the condition did not hold, which is perhaps not a very nice scenario.

Comment: Basically what I am asking, is once I get my chat room entity back, can I rest assured that the global index you mention has been updated, and, if it is truly global, this would imply the result would show up on the other clients as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I believe the answer is technically no: the "eventually" part comes from updating global indexes in multiple locations and a given client having its query served by a location that hasn't finished applying the update. But it would be unusual to need it to be otherwise. Note that you can just use the system ID or app-generated key name of the new entity, and not the full stringified Key. If your notification doesn't even have room for that and you're just telling the peers "go query for it," then you need an ancestor query.

Comment: (Note that this invalidates part of my answer on polling, since technically, the same client could "poll" the index, see a result, then perform the query again and not see the new result. But that's still sufficient in most straightforward cases of a single user that uses the query result, then has a period of user interaction before needing to query again. The polling idea probably isn't the best general recommendation; it's better to just design to accommodate eventual consistency and local entity groups.)

Comment: OK, so I need to send the application generated key name for the new chat room in my C2DM request. What is the difference in length between the application generated key and the one stored on the server and why are these two keys different? As a matter of curiosity, hat happens if two applications generate the same key on the application side. I understand this is unlikely but still possible. Would one of the apps receive a server error upon trying to persist the entity?

Comment: Another solution I was thinking of, is have a separate entity called ChatRooms with a multivalued property called chatRoomNames. In this property I would store all the names of all the chatrooms and since this is a single entity querying it for this property would always be strongly consistent. Then every client can be sure of what the complete list of entities is and poll appropriately the entity/chat room of interest. Any ideas pertaining to whether this solution would/would not work? Any pros and cons to this design? Presumably a multivalued property can have an unlimited number of values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7365/discussion-between-dan-sanderson-and-johngoche9999)