# NDB datastore write confirmation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is there any flag activated whenever a field is updated or added to the datastore?

I have an edit handler that modifies fields(obviously) but when I return to the page where all the items are displayed, the fields appeared unchanged until I have refresh the page again. What I'm doing is simply redirecting(self.redirect) to the page where all items are post.

Comment: You are probably running into datastore's eventual vs strong consistency issue (i.e. when you put something into datastore and immediately request for it - it may not have been written into the datastore just yet), you can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing then reading entity does not fetch entity from datastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137214/writing-then-reading-entity-does-not-fetch-entity-from-datastore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the results of "eventual consistency". From a practical standpoint, there are many strategies that you can consider to address this (some technical, some just UI alternatives). Here are a couple to consider:

- Use entity groups and ancestor queries to induce strong consistency from the query (as noted in the link provided by Zig in the above comment)
- Don't redirect them immediately back to the list page -- instead take them to the details (or edit) page with a "Fields Updated" message. By the time they go back to the list page, it will be consistent.
- When the update is performed, store a copy of the now updated values into memcache under a unique key, and then redirect to the list page with an extra flag including the key. The list page would then use that key, if provided, to get and merge the just-updated values in the memcache entry into the resulting query list.

Comment: Totally helped! I added a time.sleep(0,1) before redirecting to avoid seeing eventual consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `auto_now` option of a [DateTime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time) property:

```
last_updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

This is described in more detail here: [How is the value of 'auto_now_add' determined in ndb's async operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11525269/584846)